# How to set the content of a Emacs register to some text programmatically?

Tags: registers

I was wondering how I can store certain text in a given register using elisp (so that I can set in a configuration files).

I know that I can do this manually with `C-x r s r` to store some text into the register `r`. Then, I can use it by `C-x r i r`.

I tried to set the register as follows:

```
(set-register 'r' "hI")
```

, and in the Help window I see that

> register-alist’s value is ((r . "hI"))

But, when trying to use it with `C-x r i r`, I get:

> user-error: Register does not contain text

I don't know much elisp.

*Could someone explain how to set the content of the register in elisp correctly?*

Comment: `(set-register ?r "hI")`

Comment: @Tyler Thanks! The linked question does not answer mine. I wanted something more specific, and nothing about `interactive` there. The answer there actually triggered this question. I saw mention of `set-register` there, but couldn't figure out how to use it  (due to my lack of knowledge on elisp). Hence this question.

Comment: `?r` is how Emacs Lisp represents the literal character `r` in lisp programs. The point that @Tyler is making is that the name of a register is a single character, not a string or a symbol or anything more complicated. So `(set-register ?r "hI")` sets the register named `r` to have the string `hI` as its contents.

Comment: @NickD Thanks. That's where I got it wrong. I thought it's single-quotes vs double quotes as in C/C++.

Comment: The linked question is a bit different, but the answer includes the distinction between strings ("r") and characters (?r) with respect to register names, which is the bit you were missing

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: Right - sIngle quotes are used for `quoting` in Emacs Lisp (i.e. to protect something from being evaluated)- they are *never* used as delimiters.